# Authentication error while creating mongo debezium connector

Tags: mongodb, authentication, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to create mongo debezium connector below but getting authentiation error. Please find details below

POST **http://localhost:8083/connectors**

Payload:

```
{
  "name": "mongodb-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "mongodb.hosts": "host1:27020,host2:27020",
    "mongodb.name": "op_log",
    "mongodb.user": "useradmin",
    "mongodb.password":"userpassword",
    "mongodb.authsource":"admin"
  }
}
```

Error Details

```
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='useradmin', source='config', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:61)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:44)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server 10.51.19.113:27020. The full response is { "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1585508571, "i" : 1 } }, "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed", "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1585508571, "i" : 1 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "f5msklBnUsfygvd+lCDdJVj3/a4=", "$type" : "0" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "6784723618031992833" } } } }
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.createCommandFailureException(CommandHelper.java:170)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:95)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:45)
    ... 6 more
```

See in error, mechanism is coming as null and in mongodb I am using SCRAM-SHA-1 as authentication mechanism.

Comment: Could you specify which version of debezium you are using?

Comment: I am using debezium version 1.1 Here is the detail documentation for the same:
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/mongodb.html

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved. Apparently I was using old version of mongodb connector jars(1 month old). Latest update came on 24th March 2020.

You can get those jars here - https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/mongodb.html#mongodb-deploying-a-connector